# Text is not displayed when setting the "textFormat" style for a ComboBox control's "textField" property in Flash?

Tags: actionscript-3, flash, controls, styles, components

All over the net, it says I should be able to change the fl.controls.ComboBox's style with the following code, which was originally suggested here: http://blogs.adobe.com/pdehaan/2008/03/using_embedded_fonts_with_the_3.html

```
//assumes combobox is a fl.controls.ComboBox and has been populated and has an item selected; also assumes the Arial font has been properly embedded.
var textFormat:TextFormat = new TextFormat( "Arial", 12 );
combobox.textField.setStyle( "textFormat", textFormat );
combobox.textField.setStyle( "embedFonts", true );
combobox.dropdown.setRendererStyle( "textFormat", textFormat );
combobox.dropdown.setRendererStyle( "embedFonts", embedFonts );
```

Everything works correctly except the first two lines that call setStyle on the textField property (which is a TextInput component).  The drop down's font is updated correctly and displays fine, using the embedded Arial font with whatever size I set, but the ComboBox's main text that displays the selected item's text does NOT work.  It displays nothing.

Has anyone else run into this problem or been able to reproduce it?

Comment: Can you embed the Arial font in to another textfield for a sanity check?

Comment: The font is embedded fine, and it shows up in the drop-down list of the ComboBox, but not its main text field.  Also, the code snippet was from a function that sets a ComboBox's style, so the embedFonts variable is a Boolean that's set to true when the code runs.

Answer (score 0):

I worked through the following tutorial and didn't have any issues, please try this:

[ComboBox text formatting in AS3](http://www.rockabit.com/2008/04/15/combobox-text-formatting-in-as3/)

Answer (score 0):

I was having the same problem.

Apparently you need to populate the combobox ***before*** applying any styling. I was populating mine from a list in the database, once I moved my styling code into my loader's onComplete handler, it all went good.

Hope this helps